# angular post 500 (Internal Server Error) only on server

Tags: angularjs, ajax, wcf, asp.net-ajax

locally , with the same parameters - my post work just fine.
now when i test it on our Servers in the QA version - i get the following error
"..Services/ClearingService.svc/FunctionName 500 (Internal Server Error)"

my post look like that :

```
var url = baseService + "Services/ClearingService.svc/functionName";
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data: {
            payment: payment, isNotifyOnly: isNotifyOnly , isCreateDoc : isCreateDoc
        }
    });

    request.success(function (response) {
        clearingData = response.d;
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });

    request.error(function (response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

as i've mentioned all the parameters are valid , and the version i have on my QA server is the same as the version on my local enviorment.

i susspect it has something to do with the WCF definitions.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing header information and you serializing the parameters you're posting.
Where you have

```
data: {
    payment: payment, isNotifyOnly: isNotifyOnly , isCreateDoc : isCreateDoc
}
```

Change it to:

```
data: $httpParamSerializer({
    payment: payment, isNotifyOnly: isNotifyOnly , isCreateDoc : isCreateDoc
    }),
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
```

I personally normally use $.param instead of $httpParamSerializer and that works for me. However $.param is a Jquery function and $httpParamSerializer is the angular equivalent, works exactly the same. Just don't forget to inject the $httpParamSerializer function.